# What is a common name and response for when someone gives little information for the sole purpose of getting people to ask what happened?

Tags: single-word-requests

Examples would be like someone saying:

> “Well, today was awful! I can’t believe that just happened to me!”

or

> “Wow, today is great! I’m so lucky!”

...to get others to ask what happened.

What is a common term for this?

Comment: Hi Clint, welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: It’s a bit like ‘a leading question’. Only, it’s not really, necessarily a question, so I don’t think that fits. 

Comment: If someone said to me "well today was awful" without saying more, I would respond with, "well don't leave me hanging, what happened?!" Hence for me a name for that would be, "To leave hanging", but it's hard to know if that would work in your context.

Comment: *Okay, I'll bite.*

Comment: In some contexts it's called clickbait.

Comment: @Mazura what do you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: @Ooker - It's the response. [I'll bite.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I%27ll+bite) TFD (Inf.) *Okay, I will answer your question.; Okay, I will listen to your joke or play your little guessing game.*

Comment: @Mazura i thought that it's more like you will give negative critique, which usually you don't want because that require you to articulate the reasons?

Comment: I want to say "Begging the question", but ironically begging the question is something completely different.

Comment: It's like _fishing for compliments_, but the speaker is fishing for something else... that I can't name at the moment...

Answer (score 38):

Answering/naming the activity (rather than labeling the person) is usually more artful use of English and more effective in making your point. Consider the terms "baiting" or "fishing".

[**bait**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bait):

> *verb*
>
> 8. (transitive) to entice; tempt

[**fish**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fish):

> *verb*
>
> 17. (intransitive; foll by for) to seek something indirectly
>
>     *to fish for compliments*

<sup>definitions from Collins dictionary, English section</sup>

Examples:

"Stop ***baiting*** people into asking you questions."

"You're ***fishing*** for questions. I like you, but you won't catch any today."

You might call it "question baiting" or "question fishing".

To answer the question fully, and I do not mean any sarcasm at all, if you must have a label for the actual person doing this, the urban dictionary would probably be best suited, partially because vernacular might be more effective there and mainly because we avoid single-word answer questions on ELU.

Comment: I hit the wrong button on my phone and didn't mean to make an answer, but I had to keep it in the UX. I hope this is helpful. I will remove it if it is too terrible to help. Sorry, rookie error.

Comment: Good words and explanation. The only thing missing to make it a good answer was dictionary definitions, so I've added those.

Comment: Your edit and comment here is helping to teach me as a rookie. Thank you for all of this.

Comment: 'Fishing' was the first thing that occurred to me.  I think that simply saying someone was fishing is ok given enough context.  "Fishing for sympathy" is an expression I've heard used occassionally.  "Fishing for attention" would be another possible alternative.

Comment: Also "fishing for compliments" is pretty common, so "fishing" was where I went first too.

Comment: "Baiting" was my first thought as well, though I think both would apply in this situation. They are "baiting" someone into asking a question because they are "fishing" for some kind of reaction.

Answer (score 23):

When done on social media, it goes by the name *vagueposting*. You could generalize to *vaguetalking*.

> **vagueposting**
>
> 1. Give off a vague feeling of sadness or other emotional issues to prompt others into asking what's wrong and generally shower said poster with attention

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=vagueposting)

Comment: I've specifically heard "Vaguebooking" (Facebook) and "Vaguetweeting" (Twitter).

Comment: "Vaguebooking" was what came immediately to mind for me as well.  I have never heard anyone use the word vaguetalking, but have heard vaguebooking generalized to non-digital speech as well.

"She is a constant vaguebooker-- everything she says is a ploy for attention!"

Comment: if one vaguestackexchanges, their post will be downvoted and closed for "unclear what you are asking"

Answer (score 6):

Statements of that sort could be called ***teasers***, defined variously as:

> a ... device intended to arouse interest or
>   curiosity especially in something to follow ([M/W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teaser))
>
> or
>
> a person or thing that pokes fun or raises interest, without
>   intending to satisfy ([yourdict](http://www.yourdictionary.com/teaser))

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there are any perfect matches. Still, here are a few

They are **'piquing someone’s curiosity'** or **'piquing their interest'**

> to make someone want to know more about something or someone.

Example:

> Eventually her curiosity was piqued and she went to talk to the boy.

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pique-someone-s-curiosity-interest)

I think 'piquing their interest' might be the best recognised phrase, even better when prefaced by 'deliberately', as in 'he was deliberately piquing their interest'.

They might be **'drawing someone in'**.

> If you draw someone in or draw them into something you are involved with, you cause them to become involved with it.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/draw-in)

It's not a phrase I've heard much or at all, but to **'manufacture interest'** is probably as good a fit as I can think of - as good as piquing interest, since it is clearer but less common.

On a related note there's also to **'arouse interest'** or **'raise interest'** but I don't think those are quite right, and I could not find any good source links for them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A specific version of this is called [the pronoun game](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20pronoun%20game). This is used when the "little information" given is an unspecific identifier such as "he", "she", "it" or generic terms like "there", "that", etc., forcing the other person to ask "who" or "what" or "where, exactly".

(note: The term has also been usurped in a genderism context, I'm not referring to that meaning)

Answer (score 2):

In psychology, this can be called as **priming**. You can watch [an explanatory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRAKt0GakJM), or read more on [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)).